# node, sql and jquery -> Registration form - access data on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, node.js

So I have a registration form. When I type the details and click on the submit button, that data is supposed to go directly into the mySQL database. So this is my index.html part where I do stuff when I click on the submit button.

```
            $("#reg button#submit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1/reg",
                    data: {
                        username: $("#usr").val(),
                        password: $("#pwd").val()
                    },
                    success: function (res) {
                        //
                    }

                });
            });
```

Now I save that data with ajax call, but how do I access it on the server.js?

I suppose it is with app.get() but what to do next?

```
app.get('/reg', function (req, res) {
    /// get the username and password and do a query and send them to database. How?
});
```

Comment: And to be more specific - I know how to do the queries, but I am not sure how to get the inputted data ( $("#usr").val() ) on the server and do a query

Comment: Mhm.. ? Perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you send your data from the frontend via "POST" but you are waiting in the backend for a "GET"-Request.
Change:

```
app.post('/reg', function (req, res) {
  // Your data is in req.body.username and req.body.password
});
```

And then you can insert it in your database.

Comment: Sorry, lol. That was a total screw-up on my end. You are right.

Comment: What do I do if req.body is undefined?

Comment: OK, my fault... 
do you already installed body-parser? https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser here you get the postvariables in the req.body object

Comment: The thing is that I cant install it with npm. It says Windows_NT error or something like this

Comment: or you change back to "GET" (I'm not sure if it's a good idea because you are sending username + password?) and then you should access the data via `req.query.username` and `req.query.password`

Comment: Okay, but will it work without the body-parser? I just can't download it because it fires an error

Comment: req.body contains data sent with "POST" and req.query contains data sent with "GET". But I recommend you to fix your body-parser error for the future